# ActiveChart.Deselect doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, excel-charts

I create an xy scatter chart from three columns of data -- see data sample and code below.  The code is run from an add-in, and *not* from the active workbook

After putting `SeriesCollection(1)` onto the secondary axis, that charted line is selected.
According to Excel 2007 HELP, `ActiveChart.Deselect` should deselect everything.  But it did nothing when added to my code.  `.Deselect` is listed in the Object Model Changes since Office XP as a method of the Chart Object, with a status of `hidden`.

I have found a variety of suggestions, including selecting some cell; or using SendKeys to send {ESC}.  The only method that seemed to work was to first enable screenupdating, and then protect the chart.  (The unprotect after is not necessary to remove the selection, but convenient for further work).

Is there a better method, or this a reasonable work-around?

Does `Chart.Deselect` work in other versions of Excel?

The final result should be that the chart will be visible on the screen, with nothing selected.

**Short data sample**

```
Time                    Amps    Volts
04/26/2015 01:22:39 PM  4.9     53.4
04/26/2015 01:22:40 PM  -0.9    53.2
04/26/2015 01:22:41 PM  -1.5    53.4
04/26/2015 01:22:42 PM  8.7     53.4
04/26/2015 01:22:43 PM  -2.9    53.3
04/26/2015 01:22:44 PM  -3.2    53.2
04/26/2015 01:22:45 PM  11.3    53.8
04/26/2015 01:22:46 PM  -3.8    53.3
04/26/2015 01:22:47 PM  -3.2    53.3
04/26/2015 01:22:48 PM  11.4    53.6
04/26/2015 01:22:49 PM  -3.2    53.3
04/26/2015 01:22:50 PM  -2.8    53.2
04/26/2015 01:22:51 PM   5.7    53.3
04/26/2015 01:22:52 PM   7.5    53.5
04/26/2015 01:22:53 PM   2.1    53.3
04/26/2015 01:22:54 PM   2.3    53.4
04/26/2015 01:22:55 PM   2.5    53.3
04/26/2015 01:22:56 PM   2.4    53.4
04/26/2015 01:22:57 PM   2.3    53.4
04/26/2015 01:22:58 PM   1.9    53.5
04/26/2015 01:22:59 PM   2      53.3
04/26/2015 01:23:00 PM   2.3    53.3
04/26/2015 01:23:01 PM   2.7    53.5
04/26/2015 01:23:02 PM   2.5    53.4
04/26/2015 01:23:03 PM  -2.4    53.4
04/26/2015 01:23:04 PM  -4      53.3
04/26/2015 01:23:05 PM  -3.5    53.3
04/26/2015 01:23:06 PM   4.1    53.4
04/26/2015 01:23:07 PM   9.4    53.6
04/26/2015 01:23:08 PM  -5.1    53.3
04/26/2015 01:23:09 PM   9.8    53.6
04/26/2015 01:23:10 PM  -5.2    53.2
04/26/2015 01:23:11 PM   9.7    53.5
04/26/2015 01:23:12 PM  -5.5    53.2
04/26/2015 01:23:13 PM   9.8    53.6
```

Using this code:

```
Sub GraphEmeter()
    Dim cS  As Chart
    Dim A As Axis

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set cS = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set cS = ActiveChart
With cS
    .SetSourceData Range("capture!R1").CurrentRegion, xlColumns
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    Set A = .Axes(xlCategory)
    With A
        .CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
        .BaseUnitIsAuto = True
        .TickLabels.Orientation = 45
    End With
    .SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2

    'deselect the chart area
    'documented method 
    '            ActiveChart.Deslect
    'doesn't seem to work

    'But this method does
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    .Protect
    .Unprotect

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**--Udpated Answer--**

I added your sample data, and created an add-in with your code. I confirmed that to unselect the series you can simply select the chart area with the following line:

```
cS.ChartArea.Select
```

**--Original Answer--**

***This doesn't work for the OP, but could still work when the chart isn't on a Chart sheet, but on a standard worksheet***

If the goal is to simply unselect the chart, then you should be able to select anything else on the sheet (range, object, etc.) to change the selection. I've chosen cell `A1`, but you could choose anything (like a cell located behind the chart, for example).

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: I'm guessing, even though you did not answer, that `Chart.Deselect` did not work for you.  Did your solution work when you ran my code from an add-in?  It did not work for me, so please post the full code that you used.  I was able to select a cell on another sheet, but I had to use the full `Workbooks(..).Worksheets(..).Range(..)` specification and I had to select the sheet first.  Then, of course I would have to reselect the Chart.  The '.Protect   .Unprotect' method seemed cleaner.

Comment: I did not try in an add-in. I also did not try your original `Deselect` code. I took it on your word that it wasn't working. I could make an argument that `Workbooks(..).Worksheets(..).Range(..).Select` is cleaner than `.Project/.Unprotect` as it is a bit more self-explanatory, or you could simply select the chart object instead of the range using `cS.ChartArea.Select`

Comment: In your edited answer, although your new method deselects the series, it then selects the chart area.  I am trying to end up with the chart visible and nothing selected (and I edited my question to make that absolutely clear).  *I agree that if the chart is an object on a worksheet, one can select a cell on that sheet to deselect the chart, but that is not the case with which I am dealing*

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm stumped O_o. I can't seem to record any manual action that works. Hitting {Esc} works. Clicking outside the chart area works. But I can't record any of it... Or find anything online. I'm guessing that the `.protect` version works because it tricks Excel into changing the selection in Excel.

Comment: Also, I'm using Excel 2010, and deselect does nothing for me as well.

Comment: I believe `Protect` works as written because the default protection on a chart sheet includes "protecting" the objects and content.  I suppose that could be considered a trick.  Thanks for indicating that Chart.Deselect doesn't work in 2010 either.  I wonder if they've ever fixed either Excel or the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try `ActiveChart.Des`**e**`lect` instead of `ActiveChart.Deslect`

Comment: Had that typo been in the tested code, an error message would have been generated.

Comment: True, just saw that it was commented out in the code that was pasted.

Comment: That may be, but had the typo been in running code, it would not run at all. It would cause a `Compile error`.  I don't suppose you happened to try that method on a chart on a chart sheet, and have it work, did you? If so, please share your set up.  I just tried it again in case there'd been some applicable Excel update and it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problems using this code.

```
.chart.refresh
```